# CruiseControl .NET - what to configure to avoid multiple triggering of CI builds

Tags: .net, cruisecontrol.net, teamcity

I want got CuriseControl .NET based CI process installed for my development - a small team of 15 developers, concurrently working on several projects in one solution.

Now my question is what do i need to configure so as to avoid any potential multiple concurrent CI builds getting triggered. I amy be asking a stupid question here, but nevertheless better to ask than end up in trouble :-)

Lets say i have configured the CC to check for source modifications every 2 minutes.
If one developer integrates something at 10.00 the CC will recognise that at 10.02 and start to pull source and start building, running tets etc.

In the meanwhile, if another developer checks-in something at 10.03, would the CC get triggerd again at 10.05 to pull source again and start building - while its already building on the earlier one?

Since the build folder will be same in each case, would it not be a problem.

Or would the CC know that its alraedy building it, so it will not trigger another build activation (based on teh second check-in by th second developer)?

Please help.

Answer (score 5):

Cruise-control will not check for modifications to a project while it's already building said project.

For more control over that sort of thing, check out [integration queues](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Integration+Queues).